# Why does Prettier remove quotes from "Authorization" header in fetch request?

Tags: authorization, fetch-api, prettier, request-headers

Is it acceptable to send a fetch request with the Auth header not formatted as a string?

```
fetch('...', {
  method: POST,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer...',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
})
```

Prettier auto-removes my quotes on save (single- or double-quotes), and I can't find any setting to change this. I also can't find any source online that would suggest that the Authorization header doesn't need to be sent as a string. So then is this a feature or a bug? Thanks.

Comment: objects keys are always stringified by default - `'Authorization': '...'` and `Authorization: '...'` are exactly the same

Comment: The relevant prettier rule is https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quote-props

Comment: [Optional reading](https://gavilan.blog/2019/01/03/anatomy-of-an-http-request/)